# calling this.setState() inside keen client.query.then() returns cannot read property setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keen-io

I have a keen extraction query setup inside my react component.
When I render the keen query results inside keen's table it works fine. 
The problem occurs when I try to store the query results inside the state and try to render that data in a custom data table.

Below is the code of my keen query:

```
Keen.ready(function () {
  const element = document.getElementById('keen-table-chart');
  const chart = new Keen.Dataviz()
    .el(element)
    .type('table')
    .height(400)
    .prepare();
  client
    .query('extraction', {
      event_collection: 'Arrivy Datastore',
      timeframe: 'this_30_days',
      timezone: 18000,
      filters: filtersArray,
      property_names: propertyNames
    })
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        queryResults: res
      }, () => { this.renderDataTable(res); });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      chart
        .message(err.message);
    });
});
```

`this.setState` in the `.then()` returns `Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`.

Comment: use arrow function here also: `Keen.ready(() => {`

Comment: Can you post the react component and where Keen is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your are out of the component-context. This is due to your `function`-call in the first line, which removes the `this`-context.

You will need to use `bind` or an arrow function. Since your are already using arrow functions, the code could like this.

```
Keen.ready(() => {
  const element = document.getElementById('keen-table-chart');
  const chart = new Keen.Dataviz()
    .el(element)
    .type('table')
    .height(400)
    .prepare();
  client
    .query('extraction', {
      event_collection: 'Arrivy Datastore',
      timeframe: 'this_30_days',
      timezone: 18000,
      filters: filtersArray,
      property_names: propertyNames
    })
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        queryResults: res
      }, () => { this.renderDataTable(res); });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      chart
        .message(err.message);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yup. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I'll mark your question as accepted. :)